# How to move a file via sftp to windows server?

Tags: 14.04, windows, files, cron, sftp

I want to move a test.zip file from my Ubuntu 14.04 Server to an Windows Server.

I need a bash script that does this via `sftp` every day (cronjob).

I only found ftp scripts on google, the sftp ones doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `sftp` to login using `key` which will allow you to perform the `ftp` like operation without the need for a password (you can also use `scp` - `secure copy over ssh`)

For that you'll need to create private and public keys, and to place your public key on the server.

Create keys:
Execute the following commands on Ubuntu server:

```
$> ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Press ENTER for all options prompted. No values need to be typed.

Now copy `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to your windows server

Assuming that you have OpenSSH on your windows server:

- Navigate into a .ssh subdirectory of your account home directory. You may need to enable showing hidden files to see the directory. If the directory does not exists, you need to create it first.
- Once there, open a file authorized_keys for editing. Again you may have to create this file, if this is your first key.
- select all of the text in the Public key for pasting into authorized_keys file box, and copy it to the clipboard (Ctrl+C). Then, switch back to the editor and insert the data into the open file, making sure it ends up all on one line. Save the file.
- Ensure that your account home directory, your .ssh directory and file authorized_keys are not group-writable or world-writable. Recommended permissions for .ssh directory are 700. Recommended permissions for authorized_keys files are 600. Read more about changing permissions.

To set OpenSSH server on windows: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server

Set up SSH public key authentication: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_public_key

Generating SSH public/private keys: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Comment: @stee - great :-)